# sum variables that depend on a range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data set where the gross per day per movie and the production budget is registered.

I try to find the payback period per movie with it. This is done my the

```
min{i: 0 < i < Len(gm) and sum from j=0 to i of gm j >= Production Budget}
```

When running this code, the folowing error occur.

> 'int' object is not subscript able

My other code is:

```
    for n in range (0, 4798+1):
    min(sum([grouped['Gross']])>= 'Production Budget' for grouped in range(0, 5285+1))

        genre   movie   Date    Gross   Days
    0   Action  0   2009-12-18  26752099    1
    1   Action  0   2009-12-19  25529036    2
    2   Action  0   2009-12-20  24744346    3
    3   Action  0   2009-12-21  16385820    4
    4   Action  0   2009-12-22  16086461    5

    genre   mid movie_title Release Date    Production Budget   
    0   Action  0   Avatar  2009-12-18  425000000   
    1   Adventure   2   Pirates of the Caribbean    2007-05-24  300000000   
    2   Action  3   Spectre 2015-11-06  300000000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a *[mcve]*. This will help us understand your problem better and provide a solution that works for you.

Comment: Care to add some data?.. a few rows are sufficient. Also try and fix your indentation in your existing code.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. Here are the first 5 rows of one of the datasets.     genre movie Date Gross Days
                   0 Action 0 2009-12-18 26752099 1
                   1 Action 0 2009-12-19 25529036 2
                   2 Action 0 2009-12-20 24744346 3
                   3 Action 0 2009-12-21 16385820 4
                   4 Action 0 2009-12-22 16086461 5

Comment: Update your question pls, don't put data in comments.

Comment: I see the table is 'reformed'. I will explain it in another way. The dataset contains the colums movie( which is a number to identify the movie), Days( which is the number of the the movie is released), Gross(which present the gross per day). Another dataset contains the colums movie( which is a number to identify a movie and match the first colum movie) and production budget( which represent the production budget for that movie)

Comment: Please edit your question with the data. I can't read data in comments.

Comment: I am sorry. Now the first rows of both datasets are in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your budget and use `pd.Series.cumsum` groupwise for your result.

```
budgets = df_budget.set_index('movie_title')['Production Budget']
df_gross['CumGross'] = df_gross.groupby('movie')['Gross'].cumsum()

mask = df_gross['CumGross'] > df_gross['movie'].map(budgets)

pay_back_days = df_gross.loc[mask, ['movie', 'Days']]\
                        .drop_duplicates('movie')\
                        .set_index('movie')['Days']
```